# How to close something create by disabled user in phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

In the Phabricator, almost everything create by someone can only edited by the author, but now some people have left the team, how could the administrator acquire the permissions?

Like a vote, if the author did not close it, no one can close it.

Comment: I don't use slowvote, so in that specific case I am not sure, but a lot of administrative things like this can only be done from the command-line - see the scripts in phabricator/bin and phabricator/scripts.

Comment: Thanks, but cannot find a command for this operation. I use mysql-client set the status of the slowvote to close.